# Viber - Hide the user field input when sending Keyboard Message

Tags: node.js, bots, chatbot, viber

I'm trying to send a Text Message with a keyboard. I found in the [docs](https://viber.github.io/docs/tools/keyboards/#general-keyboard-parameters) that I can hide the input field of the user by setting the value of *InputFieldState* to hidden but the user input field is still there when I send the message.

**Expected Behavior**
[image]

**Actual Behavior**
[image]

Comment: Did you manage to get it sorted? I too tried the same but It did not work. There are no options in the Admin panel to turn it off either.

Comment: Haven't had any luck @IndikaWijesooriya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.
Define the keyboard

```
const KEYBOARD_JSON = {
 "Type": "keyboard",
 "InputFieldState": "hidden",
 "Buttons": [{ // This is just an example
    "Columns": 6,
    "Rows": 1,
    "ActionType": "reply",
    "ActionBody": "Get started",
    "Text": "Get started",
    "BgColor": "#F0923F",
    "TextSize": "regular",
    "TextHAlign": "center",
    "TextVAlign": "middle",
    "Silent": "true"
 }]
}
```

define the message using the KeyboardMessage constructor with the below optional arguments.

```
const your_message = new KeyboardMessage(KEYBOARD_JSON, null, null, null, 3); // If it didn't work with min_api_version 3, try 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Viber documentation is not good enough. As I tried, You should include `"min_api_version": 4` in the JSON message.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
"InputFieldState": "minimized".

Here is an example

```
keyboard": {
    "Type": "keyboard",
    "InputFieldState": "minimized",
    "Buttons": [
      {
        "Columns": "2",
        "Rows": "2",
        "BgColor": "#000000",
        .....
        .....
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you send a TextMessage without a keyboard and then send KeyBoardMessage it's working.

Something like this :

```
bot.sendMessage(
      response.userProfile,
      new TextMessage('Test message')
    );

    setTimeout(() => {
      bot.sendMessage(
        response.userProfile,
        new KeyboardMessage(
          your_keyboard,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          3
        )
      );
    }, 500);
```

But I still can't find a way to send TextMessage with hidden input field. Because doing it like this when the TextMessage is sent, the input field will occur and after some time when the KeyBoardMessage arrives it will hide it, and that isn't something that we are looking for :)

Comment: Your way isn't solve the problem described by the author. In Viber bot API we read about onConversationStarted event: "...doesn’t allow the account to send messages to the user; however, it will allow sending one “welcome message” to the user.".
Actually, in your example you send two messages - one TextMessage and one KeyboardMessage. Unfortunately, user will receive only TextMessage in this case.

P.S. For sending two and more of messages in specially order, you can send it in array and using response arg:
response.send([new TextMessage('text'), new KeyboardMessage(options)]).

Comment: ...but in general, send one TextMessage and one KeyboardMessage separately and with additional parametets (new KeyboardMessage(options, null, null, null, 3)) is good idea for fix the problem with unworked options.InputFieldState = 'hidden' and options.Silent = true. keyboard configs. Exept in case, described by the author =)